# Tagging: SQL query to return tagged and untagged items

Tags: sql, ms-access, tagging

I'm building a database that will incorporate tagging and have gone with the 'toxi' schema where I have 3 tables:

```
Items: Item, ItemID, more fields
Tags: TagName, TagID, more fields
TagMap: TagID, ItemID
```

I'm trying to build a query that will list all of items and their tags, where many items may have no tags. I can't find a query that can do both.

The following query gets me items with tags by name, but will only pull items that *have* tags.

```
SELECT Items.Item, Tags.Tag
FROM Items INNER JOIN 
(Tags INNER JOIN TagMap ON Tags.ID = TagMap.TagId)
ON Items.ID = TagMap.ItemId;
```

The following query gets me all of the items and their TagIDs if they've been tagged, but I can't seem to get to the next step of converting those TagIDs to TagNames in a single query.

```
SELECT [Items].Item, [TagMap].TagId
FROM Items LEFT JOIN TagMap ON [Items].ID=TagMap.ItemId;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243855%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says "OUTER JOINs can be nested inside INNER JOINs in a multi-table join, but INNER JOINs cannot be nested inside OUTER JOINs," but I can't find any way of nesting the two joins that does not throw an error. As far as I can see, I need the LEFT JOIN to be on Items.

I'm working in Access to build my proof on concept database because it's already installed on my machine. I will probably switch to SQL Server at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close -- just needed to add 1 additional `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT [Items].Task, [TagMap].TagId, Tags.TagName
FROM Items 
    LEFT JOIN TagMap ON [Items].ID=TagMap.TaskId
    LEFT JOIN Tags ON TagMap.TagID=Tags.TagID
```

Since you're using MS Access, you'll need to use parentheses around your joins -- something like this should be close:

```
SELECT [Items].Task, [TagMap].TagId, Tags.TagName
FROM (Items 
    LEFT JOIN TagMap ON [Items].ID=TagMap.TaskId)
    LEFT JOIN Tags ON TagMap.TagID=Tags.TagID
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If I may ask, why another LEFT JOIN? To me, the mapping in of the tags seemed like it really had to be an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @alwayssummer -- np, glad I could help.  You'll want to use the LEFT JOINs in case the records don't exists in the TagMap and/or Tags tables.  This way, you'll always receive the Items.Task field, but potentially receive NULL values for the TagId and/or TagName fields (like in your example).  Best of luck!